# WLAN Networkmanager Xubuntu 18

Tags: drivers, wireless, xubuntu

*As I was asking about WIFI that was possible to enable in the earlier question,* I now see the connection enabled, a pop-up tells to "view the network menu..." but that network menu is nowhere to find.

And I can not view available WIFI connections meaning I have no way to select and click any from the display, however, I can as always, see the wired connection for the Ethernet in "Network Connections" though.

WIFI and Bluetooth were both possible with Ethernet to enable and disable in another view from the display.

In my Ubuntu 16 on a Hp Mini anno 2010 I have the sound, battery, contrast seen in the display's right corner but they are like the connections view not missing (even only WIFI is critical here)  What can I do?

Many thanks indeed.
9th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-9750H Processor (2.60GHz, up to 4.50GHz with Turbo Boost, 6 Cores, 12MB Cache)

Wireless
802.11 AC (2 x 2) & Bluetooth® 4.1
https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-y-series/Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15/p/88GMY501214

Comment: We do not understand, "I now see the connection. But I can not view the connections". Please clarify. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry and Thanks, I did this now

Comment: Does the network icon appear if you do the command: `nm-applet &` Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, well, running      nm-applet &         made no visible change I am afraid. It was on the CMD showing 1320 if that means anything to you.

Comment: 1st time,  [1] 1382

Comment: 2nd time (in a row) 2  1386

Comment: Please stop. If it didn't help the first time, it won't help the tenth time or the hundredth time.

Comment: next line under 1386 it says          1 Done         nm-applet   (but 0 shows)

Comment: Do you see the up-down arrows like in this image? https://cdn.instructables.com/FAB/3UPZ/GVMITD2F/FAB3UPZGVMITD2F.LARGE.jpg

Comment: Thanks, no I do not, I see notification computer volume and dates, meaning the difference is the arrows

Comment: Is Network Manager even running? `ps aux | grep -i network`

Comment: erikajana@erikajana-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~$ ps aux | grep -i network
root       512  0.0  0.0  35840 14184 ?        Ssl  17:08   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
root       548  0.0  0.0  71984 14864 ?        Ssl  17:08   0:02 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
erikaja+  2150  0.0  0.0   8068   868 pts/0    S+   19:57   0:00 grep --color=auto -i network
erikajana@erikajana-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~$

Comment: It appears to be running normally. Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep etwork` As the output may be lengthy, post the result here amd give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BX9fYFwy3h/

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TRjX5Gmv3g/

Comment: While adding the camera to the panel, the wireless showed up... thx so much for the trouble, you have been very patient and friendly. Where can I close this question as solved and give you kudos?